# Docker Machine vs Virtual Machine

Tags: docker-machine

I've been reading recently about docker machine , and while I get roughly what's the general idea , I'm still not very clear about some points, specifically :

1. when you create a regular VM from Vmware, you define : RAM,CPU,HDD,etc or in the case of cloud, the instance type/size.. however , with docker-machine seems you only specify driver and machine name ... how does docker machine know what instance type/size or hardware specs to use ?
2. How is connecting using docker-machine different from doing SSH directly into my VMs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more on the online documentation , I found that the different VM drivers include some commands for defining RAM , CPU , HDD (`--virtualbox-cpu-count`  , `--virtualbox-memory` , and `--virtualbox-disk-size` ) , else it'll use some default values (i.e : 1 CPU)

But more importantly the iso this product uses is Boot2Docker, which is "**DEPRECATED**" , also with more powerful orchestration tools out there ... I guess there's no room for Docker Machine (R.I.P)